# zlib output memory buffer size error

Tags: c, zlib

I am trying to compress image data using zlib's `compress()` function. For this purpose I allocate memory equal to `compressBound()` of input data to the output buffer. But I keep getting the `Z_BUF_ERROR`. Why is it happening ?

```
for (y = 0; y < header.cupsHeight; y ++)
{
    pixdata = malloc(header.cupsBytesPerLine);

    if(pixdata==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error in memory allocation for pixdata\n");
        return -1;
    }
    cupsRasterReadPixels(ras, pixdata, header.cupsBytesPerLine);

    destLen = compressBound(header.cupsBytesPerLine);
    fprintf(stderr, "mem. dest. = %lld\n",destLen);
    write_buffer = malloc(destLen);
    if(write_buffer==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error in memory allocation for write_buffer\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ret = compress(write_buffer, &destLen, pixdata, header.cupsBytesPerLine);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        zerr(ret);
    fwrite(write_buffer, 1, destLen, stdout);
    free(write_buffer);
        free(pixdata);
    }
```

Error checking of value returned is performed by this function:

```
/* report a zlib or i/o error */
void zerr(int ret)
{
    fputs("zpipe: ", stderr);
    switch (ret) {
    case Z_ERRNO:
        fputs("error in source data or output file\n", stderr);
        break;
    case Z_STREAM_ERROR:
        fputs("invalid compression level\n", stderr);
        break;
    case Z_DATA_ERROR:
        fputs("invalid or incomplete deflate data\n", stderr);
        break;
    case Z_MEM_ERROR:
        fputs("out of memory\n", stderr);
        break;
    case Z_VERSION_ERROR:
        fputs("zlib version mismatch!\n", stderr);
        break;
    case Z_BUF_ERROR:
            fputs("error in buffer\n",stderr);
            break;
    }
}
```

When I run the program each time the `compress()` function is called, I get `zpipe: error in buffer` (the last case in `zerr()` function). Also memory allocation does not fail as I have included the condition for it and it evaluates to false each time the loop is called.

Comment: What version of zlib? Can you provide an example of uncompressed data for which this happens?

Comment: zlib version 1.2.8. Example means? The data I am trying to compress is image pixel data.

Comment: Yes, that data. Can you provide an example of the exact data that you fed to `compress()` that resulted in compressed data that did not fit in what was returned by `compressBound()`?

Comment: @MarkAdler   The image data is extracted from an 8 bit per color raster file. I have uploaded the file here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-wSviYjd5oCQ2RkN2FBeE5aU0k

Comment: What I want is the exact data that you fed to _one_ `compress()` call with a buffer sized using `compressBound()` that resulted in a `Z_BUF_ERROR`.

Comment: What is the value of `header.cupsBytesPerLine` for the uploaded file?

Comment: What is the type of `destLen`? If it is not equivalent to an `unsigned long`, then that could be the problem.

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes, the problem was `destLen` was declared `unsigned int` by me. Making it `unsigned long` solved the problem.

Comment: You really need to turn on more warnings on your compiler. It can help you with things like that. Also next time provide the complete source code of at least the function. Then we could have seen the problem immediately.

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes I'll follow your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the memory bound for compressing some number of bytes:

```
destLen = compressBound(header.cupsBytesPerLine);
```

But, then you attempt to compress 1 more byte than what you had computed the bound for.

```
ret = compress(write_buffer, &destLen, pixdata, header.cupsBytesPerLine+1);
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I was experimenting with that thing and that's why I thought of trying +1. But actually, the error persists even without that +1. I have edited it in the source code. Sorry

Comment: Was `destLen` zero?